# What is the difference between these two falling rope motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, string

Here are two falling rope problems in Marion's Classical Dynamics Textbook and both equations of motion given by manual solution.

(There is a typo in the third line of solution 9.15, one of the terms of velocity derivative should be time derivative of mass.)

Suggested by solution below, in Problem 9.15, the moving part will only be the falling part, and in Problem 9.21, the entire rope is moving. By these two different set up, there will be energy lost in 9.15 and no energy lost in 9.21.

However, I can't find out the difference of these two kinds of motion. I firstly solve both of them by energy conservation, then, my friend gives an explanation which 9.15s is affected by the tension force which is non-conservative force and gives the result of energy lost, but I thought 9.21s should be also.

Where does the 9.15s energy goes and why does the 9.21s doesn't lost energy?

Is it affected by the shape of the rope or the length of the rope? If affected by shape, the initial shape should be a control factor (such as a curly rope) respect to the final result, seems not reasonable.

I really need some clues, thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 9.15 only the part of the rope below the table is accelerating, so the equation of motion is

$m g = m \dot v + \dot mv$

where $m(t)=\sigma x$ is the mass of the rope below the table at time $t$.

In 9.21 the whole rope is accelerating, so the equation of motion is

$mg = M \dot v$

where $m(t) = \frac {Mx} L$ is the mass of the rope below the table at time $t$ and $M$ is the mass of the whole rope. Since $M$ is constant we do not need an $\dot Mv$ term here.

Energy is lost to the environment in 9.15 because of friction between the rope and the table and between different parts of the coiled rope. There is no friction in 9.21.